# OAuth2.0 Flutter serverAuthCode to get Access Token at Spring backend server

Tags: spring, flutter, spring-security, oauth

I'm struggling with the OAuth google login process.

I can get the serverAuthCode using google_sign_in at my Flutter app.

then I want to get **Access Token.**

But I think send Access Token from Flutter to my Spring backend server is not a good choice for security.

So I want to send my serverAuthCode to my Spring backend Server.

1. My first question is that the process(send serverAuthCode to backend) is right?
   1-1 if not what is the right process?
2. Second question is how can i get AccessToken at my Spring server using serverAuthCode.